# what is Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference in node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to make a web app by using node.js and react for tutoring. And when I am running the program I am getting a type error in my front end.

My code for a particular teacher(an user) is:

```
return (
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-12">
      <div className="card card-body bg-info text-white mb-3">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-4 col-md-3 m-auto">
            <img
              className="rounded-circle"
              src={studentprofile.user.avatar}
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="text-center">
          <h1 className="display-4 text-center">{studentprofile.user.name}</h1>
          <p className="lead text-center">
            {studentprofile.status}{' '}
            {isEmpty(studentprofile.company) ? null : (
              <span>at {studentprofile.company}</span>
            )}
          </p>
          {isEmpty(studentprofile.location) ? null : <p>{studentprofile.location}</p>}
          <p>
            {isEmpty(studentprofile.website) ? null : (
              <a
                className="text-white p-2"
                href={studentprofile.website}
                target="_blank"
              >
                <i className="fas fa-globe fa-2x" />
              </a>
            )}

            {isEmpty(studentprofile.social && studentprofile.social.twitter) ? null : (
              <a
                className="text-white p-2"
                href={studentprofile.social.twitter}
                target="_blank"
              >
                <i className="fab fa-twitter fa-2x" />
              </a>
            )}

            {isEmpty(studentprofile.social && studentprofile.social.facebook) ? null : (
              <a
                className="text-white p-2"
                href={studentprofile.social.facebook}
                target="_blank"
              >
                <i className="fab fa-facebook fa-2x" />
              </a>
            )}

            {isEmpty(studentprofile.social && studentprofile.social.linkedin) ? null : (
              <a
                className="text-white p-2"
                href={studentprofile.social.linkedin}
                target="_blank"
              >
                <i className="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x" />
              </a>
            )}

            {isEmpty(studentprofile.social && studentprofile.social.youtube) ? null : (
              <a
                className="text-white p-2"
                href={studentprofile.social.youtube}
                target="_blank"
              >
                <i className="fab fa-youtube fa-2x" />
              </a>
            )}

            {isEmpty(studentprofile.social && studentprofile.social.instagram) ? null : (
              <a
                className="text-white p-2"
                href={studentprofile.social.instagram}
                target="_blank"
              >
                <i className="fab fa-instagram fa-2x" />
              </a>
            )}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

I am having error in:

```
href={studentprofile.social.twitter}
                target="_blank"
```

The error which is displayed is:
TypeError: Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Examine your object (studentprofile), if all others doesn't throw exception twitter may be null, or even social.

Comment: I have examined it still I am getting the error.

Comment: You use of `isEmpty` is a bit strange, if you mean to verify that the values exist and are a string the following would work better `if (typeof studentprofile.social !== 'undefined' && typeof studentprofile.social.twitter === 'string')`. The way you have it written does not actually verify that both values exist and are of the correct type.